# Prohibir navegar a otra URL sin iniciar la sesión en Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un inicio de sesión a través de Token realizado con Angular. Una vez inicio sesión (con los datos correctos) navego hacia otra ventana de esta forma:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('grupo');
```

Y además guardo en el localStorage el **access_token** y el **expire_in**. Pero si en lugar de iniciar sesión, solo cambia la ruta en la URL también puedo acceder.

Necesito añadir esta seguridad, que hasta que no se inicia sesión no se pueda navegar a otra pestaña en ningún caso. **¿Pero como se haría esto?**

Este es el método post que tengo:

```
this.http.post(this.url,this.login,opciones)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    if(data){

    this.TOKEN = data["access_token"];
    this.EXPIRES = data["expires_in"];

    localStorage.setItem('TOKEN',this.TOKEN);
    localStorage.setItem('EXPIRE_IN', this.EXPIRES);

    this.router.navigateByUrl('grupo');

  }
},
  error => alert("Fallo de sesion")
)
```

Y estas las opciones para el POST:

```
const opciones = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': '--lo que sea--'
  }),
  params: parametros
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que implementar un `guard` para decidir si se puede navegar a esa ruta o no. Como quieres validar que el usuario esté logueado antes de navegar a esa ruta puedes crear un guard para ello.

Cuando implementas un `guard` en angular tienes que implementar la interfaz `CanActivate`. Luego defines el guard en la ruta que quieras que tenga el `guard` y el acceso a dicha ruta esté controlado por él.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como lo podrías implementar.

```
// este es un servicio bastante simple para que entiendas el concepto
// tu puedes implementarlo como mejor se adecue a tu caso
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  get isLogged() {
    return localStorage.getItem('TOKEN') && localStorage.gettem('EXPIRE_IN');
  }
}
```

`authentication.guard.ts`
Lo puedes generar con el [siguiente comando](https://angular.io/cli/generate#guard-command) de  la CLI de angular

```
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private auth: AuthService,
    ) { }

    // este es el método que usará angular para permitir el acceso o no a la ruta.
    // tal como puedes ver en la declaración de este método, el return puede ser un boleano, observable, promesa o UrlTree
    // en este caso, es boleano
    // tienes que saber que este método se ejecutará siempre antes de activar la ruta
    // en el que esté definido
    // si devuelve true se permite el acceso de lo contrario no
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
        return this.auth.isLogged;
    }
}
```

En tu `app.module.ts` o otro módulo que tengas defines el guard.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'grupo',
        component: GroupComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AuthenticationGuard]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Documentación sobre [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Comment: Genial, voy a probarlo. Una duda que me surge: ¿donde es mejor almacenar el access_token y el expire_in? localStorage, sessionStorage o en las cookies?

Comment: En Session Storage no te lo recomiendo porque la "sesión" para el navegador concluye cuando la pestaña se cierra o escribes en la barra de direcciones una URL de otro dominio, así que sería equivalente a tener una variable estática en tu service, guardándolo. En localStorage se guarda indefinidamente, pero si el token en sí tiene caducidad eso no es un problema. Con las cookies pues tienes la opción de que se borre sola, cuando caduque. Así que ya es cuestión de gustos

Comment: tal como dice @PabloLozano es correcto. Si usas una api rest y te devuelve un token yo personalmente uso localStorage y el tema de cookies solo lo uso cuando no es una SPA y el server es el que devuelve la cookie.

Comment: @hawks cuando añado la clase a providers se queda en blanco y me aparece un error de Angular JIT, y si la quito de providers e intento iniciar sesion correctamente me salta otro error

Comment: Arreglado. Me faltaba un @Injectable()